# Gem Devise - How to redirect user to specific url only if user signed in with token?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Using Devise Gem in my project and does anybody know how to redirect user to specific url only if user signed in with token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating a your own SessionsController which you can find on  [git](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb)

like this:

```
# POST /resource/sign_in
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    #here you can enter your specific token code
    # I guess you would do it with something like:
    # if session[:token] = XYZ
    #   respond with ...
    # else 
    #   respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    # end
  end
end
```

for using this controller you also have to change your `config/routes.rb`

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => "sessions"}
```

hope it helps you :)

Comment: have not tried it yet, but this looks like a path to resolve my question

Answer (score 0):

If i am getting your question right so you are asking that how to redirect user after he/she sign's in.

So i ve tried this in my project

Here is the code

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
# Use the route you want here (i have given the url like this: '/show')
end
```

Hope i am taking the right meaning of the question.!! :)